# cannot get the values from an array

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array, zend-framework2, fgetcsv

This is a sample array from a csv file upload, which I'm working on

```
$csvData = array(7) { 
               [" Account Number"]=> string(32) " 1011001562781010" 
               [" Posting Date"]=> string(10) "07/08/2014" 
               [" Value Date"]=> string(10) "07/08/2014"
               [" Description"]=> string(46) "Cash Withdrawal by Cheque173320--TT1421957901"
               [" Debit Amount"]=> string(7) "2000.00"  
               [" Credit Amount"]=> string(0) "" 
               ["Running Balance"]=> string(9) "388392.62" 
            }
```

While trying to fetch value using the **$csvData** ,I get the following error,

> Notice: Undefined index: **Account Number**

This is my code:

```
foreach ($csvData as $csvRow) {
    $csvData[$key] =$csvRow[$this->_csvColumnAccountNumber];
    if (strtolower($csvRow[$this->_csvColumnAccountNumber]) === $csv_ied_account_number) {
        $CsvValues[$key] = $csvRow[$this->_csvColumnCreditAmount];
        $CsvValues[$key] = $csvRow[$this->_csvColumnDebitAmount];
    }
}
```

I'm really stuck on this small issue.
Please help me solve this as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is $key coming from?

Comment: private $_csvColumnAccountNumber = 'Account Number';

Comment: You have a single dimensional associative array in $csvData above.  foreach is not what you want.

Comment: ohh,more on that Devon.What else should I be using?

Comment: Also your keys are having white-space in the beginning. that may cause problem also. use trim($key) wherever you use that $key. and first try to echo $csvData[" Account Number"] and see what's comming?

Comment: i'm new to php,could you please demonstrate?

Comment: first of all what is said just do that try with echo directly don't use foreach loop right now.

Comment: What is the $csvData you put in the first block?  Did you run var_dump($csvData) before the foreach?  If not, do that, so we can see an actual example.

Comment: I've run var_dump($csvData) before foreach,thats how I got the array mentioned above.

Comment: $csvData is the array here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$csvData** is a single dimensional associative array.  If you run `foreach ($csvData as $csvRow)` **$csvRow** is going to be each value ('1011001562781010', '07/08/2014', and so on) which is not what you want, considering you are trying to access the key which won't be available.

So the first problem is you don't need a *foreach*.  `$csvData[' Account Number']` is what you are after.

This brings us to the second problem.  You have white space in your key.  You should run **[trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)** on the data when creating **$csvData** to get rid of the whitespace.  Otherwise, you can do an **[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)** and trim the data with an anonymous function:

```
array_walk($csvData, function($value, $key) use (&$csvData) {
  unset($csvData[$key]);
  $csvData[trim($key)] = $value;
});
```

Above is a pretty complex example for beginners.  What this does is goes through every element in *$csvData* and runs the callback (function) provided.  This function will unset the current key and define a new trimmed key.  You have to use `use (&$csvData)` to provide a reference to *$csvData* in the function's scope.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is really like this:

```
array(7) { [" Account Number"]=> string(32) " 1011001562781010" 
[" Posting Date"]=> string(10) "07/08/2014" 
....
[" Credit Amount"]=> string(0) "" 
["Running Balance"]=> string(9) "388392.62" }
```

Then attempt for reading a key `"Account Number"` **definitely** will fail. Because keys `"Account Number"` and `" Account Number"` (with one space before `A`) are different keys. You should use **exact** key names for accessing array elements. I advise you to refactor procedure of filling `$csvData` with values and use `trim` function for keys.